# Read blob's in secure sandboxed iframe on Safari?

Tags: javascript, iframe, https, safari, content-security-policy

This snippet below works fine in all browser running http
But when i run this with https in Safari this ain't working.
It works fine in Chrome with both http & https...

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" srcdoc="
  <script>
    var blob = new Blob(['abc']);
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsText(blob);
    fr.onerror = () => document.body.innerText = 'fail'
    fr.onload = () => document.body.innerText = fr.result
  </script>
"></iframe>
```

I'm guessing this is not a sandbox restriction but rather a [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) thing that can be solved with the right csp context

I'm hosting this on a static page so i can't solve it with headers
but the meta tag works fine also...

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content=' <duno> '>
```

So here is my question: What csp do I need to use in order to allow reading blobs in a iframe?

I did also create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgh27rre/1/) for this

Answer (score 2):

You can never use a CSP directive to make a more liberal policy than anything created by a CSP policy already applied from somewhere else. For example, you can’t override a more-strict CSP header with a more-liberal policy specified using `meta` in document.

See [the stuff about multiple policies in the CSP spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#multiple-policies):

> The impact is that adding additional policies to the list of policies to enforce can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected resource.

So to the degree that CSP is even relevant at all in this blob-with-iframe-sandbox-allow-script case, if you were to consider it as the browser applying a restrictive CSP policy on its own by default, I wouldn’t imagine you could use a CSP header or `meta` element to ease the restrictions—instead you could only use the header or `meta` element to enforce further restrictions.

Anyway, interested to see what reply you get to https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170075.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - useful information but don't solve the FileReader issue so i give you a +1. Guess I'm stuck with getting stuff done with base64, text and arraybuffers for now... Somewhat happy to see that you found my bug report :)